# Laravel - How to define multiple Resource Controllers?

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can I add multiple Resource Controllers to my Routes file? I've tried the following:

```
Route:resource('customer', 'CustomerController');
Route:resource('loan', 'LoanController');
```

but it doesn't work. "Label 'Route' already defined" exception appears

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo - you are using one colon `:` when it should be double `::`

```
Route::resource('customer', 'CustomerController');
Route::resource('loan', 'LoanController');
```